# SQL/PHP How To Display Unique User Information On The User Profile Page

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

I have a PHP page which should display the currently logged in users information like firstname, lastname, etc. The only problem I am having on the page is that it only displays the first user account within the database which happens to be the admin account on any user account I am logged in with on my website which is false as the information on there should be unique for each user.

DATABASE INFO:

PRIMARY KEY: user_id

Database connection code(init.inc.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

@mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('loginsystem');

$path = dirname(__FILE__);

include("user.inc.php");

$_SESSION['uid'] = 1;

?>
```

My backend code (user.inc.php):

```
function fetch_users(){
    $result = @mysql_query('SELECT `user_id` AS `id`, `user_uid` AS `username` FROM users');

    $users = array();

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
        $users[] = $row;
    }
    return $users;
}

//fetches profile info for the given user
function fetch_user_info($uid){
    $uid = (int)$uid;

    $sql = "SELECT `user_uid` AS `username`, `user_first` AS `firstname`, `user_last` AS `lastname`, `user_email` AS `email` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = {$uid}";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
//Updates the current users profile.
function set_profile_info($username, $firstname, $lastname, $email){
    $firstname   = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);
    $lastname    = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
    $email       = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($email));

    $sql = "SELECT `user_first` AS `firstname`, `user_last` AS `lastname`, `user_email` AS `email` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = {$uid}";

    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Frontend code (edit_profile.php):

```
<?php

include('init.inc.php');

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email'])){
    $errors = array();

    if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        $errors[] = 'The email address you entered is not valid.';
    }
    if(preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z ]+$#i', $_POST['firstname']) === 0){
        $errors[] = 'Your first name must only contain a-z characters only.';
    }
    if(preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z ]+$#i', $_POST['lastname']) === 0){
        $errors[] = 'Your last name must only contain a-z characters only.';
    }

    if (empty($errors)){
        set_profile_info($_POST['username'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email']);
    }
    $user_info = array(
        'username'   => htmlentities($_POST['username']),
        'firstname'  => htmlentities($_POST['firstname']),
        'lastname'   => htmlentities($_POST['lastname']),
        'email'      => htmlentities($_POST['email'])
    );
}else{
    $user_info = fetch_user_info($_SESSION['uid']);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>
  <head>
  <title>Edit Your Profile</title>
  <style type="text/css">

    form div {color: white; font-weight: bold; float: left; clear: both; margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px; }
    label {font: 19px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif; color: white; font-weight: bold; float:left; clear:both; margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px; }
    input[type="text"], textarea {font: 16px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif; margin-left: 10px; float:left; width: 400px; }
    input[type="submit"] {
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s;
    background: #333;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5), 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font: 17px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 39%;
    }
    input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #e3e3e3;
    color: #333;
    }
  </style>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
        <section id="showcase1">



    <div>
        <?php

        if(isset($errors) === false){
            echo 'Click update to edit your profile';
        }else if(empty($errors)) {
            echo 'Your profile has been updated.';
        }else{
            echo '<ul><li>', implode('</li><li>', $errors), '</li></ul>';
        }

        ?>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username: <?php echo $user_info['username'] ?></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $user_info['firstname'] ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $user_info['lastname'] ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email:    </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $user_info['email'] ?>" />
        </div>
        <!--<div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" />
        </div> -->
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        </div>
    </form>
   </section>
  </body> 
</html>
```

UPDATES:
login.inc.php code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include 'dbh.inc.php';

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    //Error handlers
    //Check if inputs are empty
    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' OR user_email='$uid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck < 1) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            exit();
        } else {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                //De-hashing the password
                $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
                if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
                    exit();
                } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                    //log in the user here
                    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                    $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                    $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                    $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];

                    header("Location: ../homepage.php");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

The database file the login.inc.php uses:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "loginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

Comment: **obligatory** mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Where is `$uid` defined?

Comment: You always use `$uid` 1 so that would probably be your admin

Comment: @aynber I've edited my code above to include that part of the code, sorry for not including it before :)

Comment: @RonNabuurs I see, would you possibly know how to be able to get that number change for each user that logs into the website?

Comment: @INeedHelp you should create a login function. Now you only have a fetch_user_info function. The login function should have a username and password or something similar and would get a matching user from the database. The user from the database has all the info you need

Comment: @RonNabuurs Seems promising dude, I'll give it a go and keep you update :)

Comment: @INeedHelp you really just need to read some tutorials or watch some video about php and databases / session and login.

Comment: @RonNabuurs Yeah will do, hope i can find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mysql_* functions are deprecated. try to use at least mysqli_*

In your script $_SESSION['uid'] = 1; is hard coded into your init.inc.php file. Your need to assign the  $_SESSION['uid'] dynamically.
In the case of user login, (after user verification) try to grab that user *uid* according to your code it seems like *user_id*. Then assign it to your $_SESSION['uid']. It something like

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = $raw['user_id'];
```

So now you can use $_SESSION['uid'] to fetch user details to edit em. 
If you post your login auth php file, may be I can help you more.

Comment: Thank you dude, that scrip does seem like the main problem, changing the value of that to another number does load different user profiles. I'm new to all this and your help with the login auth php file would defiantly be very helpful and is much appreciated. I've edited my post to include it :)

Comment: Oh! try this -> Remove `$_SESSION['uid'`] from _init.inc.php_ and then `$user_info = fetch_user_info($_SESSION['uid']);` to `$user_info = fetch_user_info($_SESSION['u_id']);` because you are assigning  _user_id_ to `$_SESSION['u_id']` . Hope this will work

Comment: Is this answered? Because I am encountering the same problem